# Convert cv::Mat to Mat_<float>

Tags: c++, opencv, casting, computer-vision

Hi I am computing a vector which I put in a variable

```
Mat dst;
```

Where `dst` is filled with:

```
cv::undistortPoints(points, dst, camera_matrix_Mat_, distCoeffs, rectificationMatrix);
```

I would like to do:

```
Mat_<float> vector1 = ( camera_matrix_Mat_^(-1) ) * vectorRectified;
```

where (for example):

```
Mat_<float> camera_matrix_Mat_(3,3);
camera_matrix_Mat_ << 1.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.1, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0;
```

and `vectorRectified` is built as 3x1 vector:

```
[dst(0) dst(1) 1]'
```

I was trying to do :

```
vectorRectified << (float)(dst(0)), 0.1, 1.0;
```

But it doesn't work. I tried to cast `dst(0)` but no luck. What am I missing there?

Thanks.

Comment: `Mat1f vectorRectified = (Mat1f(3,1) << float(dst(0)), float(dst(1)), 1.f)`, depending on what's exactly `dst`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I continue to get:
error: invalid cast from type ‘cv::Mat’ to type ‘float’
                     Mat1f vectorRectified = (Mat1f(3,1) << float(dst(0)), float(dst(1)), 1.f);

Comment: _depending on what's exactly `dst`_ ... What's `dst`? How did you filled it?

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: `Mat1f vectorRectified = (Mat1f(3,1) << dst.at<float>(0), dst.at<float>(1), 1.f)`

Comment: Thanks it works. I did not know about this. If you want to answer to my question in a separate answer I can accept your answer.